# How can I open multiple Excel files and execute a contained macro on each?

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I'm looking to open multiple Excel files and run the same  macro (contained in each) on each file.

For example, I'd like to automatically open every file in h:\dbs and execute the `CmdUpdate_Click` macro within each file.

How might I go about this?

Comment: First, walk through a tutorial on VBA, like this one: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba.html.  You'll need the workbooks.Open() method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx.  Once you've given it a shot and are stuck, post your issues here and we will be happy to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. I expect you can research how to open the Visual Basic Editor and figure out where to paste this.

```
'Declare variables

Dim FolderObj, FSO, FileObj As Object
Dim FolderDialog As FileDialog

'Create and run dialog box object

Set FolderDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With FolderDialog
    .ButtonName = "Select"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = "B:\BIM Projects\"
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails

    'Check if user canceled dialog box
    'Exit if yes
    If .Show = -1 Then
        MsgBox "No Folder Selected"
        Exit Sub
    End If

End With

'Check if user canceled dialog box
'Exit if yes


'Create a File System Object to be the folder that was selected

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

Set FolderObj = FSO.getfolder(FolderLocation)


'For each obj in the selected folder
For Each FileObj In FolderObj.Files

    'Test if the file extension contains "xl" and make sure it's an Excel file before opening
    If InStr(1, Right(FileObj.Name, Len(FileObj.Name) - InStr(1, FileObj.Name, ".")), "xl") = 1 Then

        'Prevent the workbook from displaying
        ActiveWindow.Visible = False

        'Open the Workbook
        Workbooks.Open (FolderObj & "\" & FileObj.Name)

        'Run the Macro
        Application.Run "'" & FolderObj & "\" & FileObj.Name & "'!CmdUpdate_Click"

        'Save the Workbook
        Workbooks(FileObj.Name).Save

        'Close the Workbook
        Workbooks(FileObj.Name.Close

    End If

'Turn this back on
ActiveWindow.Visible = True
Next
```

I will caution you that this is based on some code I wrote for Word, so there are no guarantees it will work and I don't have time to test it. It will, however, give you a very good start if it doesn't.

Edit to Add: You may